# How to find a specific file recursively and delete the last line from all files found in linux?

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I want to find a specific file `e.g. foo.txt` recursively and delete the last line from it if the line contains a specific word `(e.g. bar)`. Basically combine -

```
find . -type f -iname "foo.txt"
sed '$d' foo.txt
```

```
dir1 -
      |-sub-dir1-
                 |-foo.txt
      |-sub-dir2-
                 |-foo.txt
      |-
      .
      .
      |-
      |-sub-dirn-
                 |-foo.txt
```

Delete last line from all `foo.txt` files under `dir1` if the last line contains `bar`.

Original contents -

```
foo.txt
1
2
bar
```

After deletion -

```
foo.txt
1
2
```

Thanks.

Comment: People on SO don't take too kindly to just asking for an answer to some problem – I would suggest trying it yourself first and then asking if you still have trouble. If you have already tried it, add your attempt and what went wrong to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-exec` option to run the `sed` command. Add the `/bar/` regular expression to check that the last line also matches that pattern.

```
find . -type f -iname "foo.txt" -exec sed -i '${/bar/d;}' {} +
```